# Wordpress and Bootstrap top level menu item hover and link to url

Tags: jquery, wordpress

This is what i'm trying to achieve.

Make a top level bootstrap menu item link to a page, but also display the sub menu on hover.

I found some code which I added to my child theme's function.php.  It changes the link to be clickable, but the click makes the submenu come up.  I want the submenu to come up but only on hover and the click then opens the page of the menu item.

I'm not a coder, so if anybody could take a look and see what's wrong, I would be very grateful.

Here's the code I've got so far:

```
function  custom_nav_menu_link_attributes( $atts, $item, $args ){
  if ( !wp_is_mobile() && $args->has_children  ) {
            $atts['href'] = ! empty( $item->url ) ? $item->url : '';
    }
  return $atts;
}

add_filter( 'nav_menu_link_attributes', 'custom_nav_menu_link_attributes', 99, 3 );

function func_make_menu_clickable(){
if ( !wp_is_mobile() ) { ?>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){      
      if($(window).width() >= 767){
        $('li.menu-item a').click(function(){
          window.location = $(this).attr('href');
        });
      }
    });
  </script>
  <style type="text/css">
  @media all and (min-width: 767px) {
  .menu-item-has-children:hover > ul {
  display: block;
}
}
  </style>
<?php }
}
```

Thanks

D

Comment: This is not very clear. Please consider adding the HTML part and other CSS if any. Also, this looks to be the part where your logic is, so please check the 'if' conditions if they are intentional : 
 If($(window).width() >= 767){
        $('li.menu-item a').click(function(){
          window.location = $(this).attr('href');
        });
      }

Comment: how do you call `func_make_menu_clickable`

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer, but it adds another question...

After a lot of trial and error, I found a solution.

I found the following additional code and added it to a plugin I had installed called custom JS and CSS:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ){
jQuery(function($) {
    if($(window).width()>769){
        $('.navbar .dropdown').hover(function() {
            $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').first().stop(true, true).delay(250).slideDown();

        }, function() {
            $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').first().stop(true, true).delay(100).slideUp();

        });

        $('.navbar .dropdown > a').click(function(){
            location.href = this.href;
        });

    }
});
});
```

Somehow my top level links now link to pages, and when I hover over them the submenu shows.

If I take out the intial code in my functions.php file and/or deactivate the above js code then the top level items do not link to a page.  Seems each piece of code needs each other to work.  I'm not a coder so can't tell you why.

The only small adjustment I would like to make now, and this is the **new question**, is I would ideally like to make the top level menu item not link to a page when the website is on mobile (I know, that's why the Bootstrap code is the way it is).

Anyway, at least I've solved half my problem.

Thanks to anybody who has even bothered to read this...

D